# Django Ajax Call to Return Quantity

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

Currently using the django-carton app, I have a django view that returns JSON data that I use in an ajax call. Broadly speaking, I have got it working but struggling to work out how I can pass my item quantity (using ajax).

Within the template I can call my item quantities using:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
{{ item.quantity }}
```

The ajax call connects to the view to return the Json data:

```
def cart_detail_api_view(request):
    # cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    products = [{"name": x.name, "price": x.price} for x in cart.products]
    cart_data = {"products": products, "total": cart.total}
    return JsonResponse(cart_data)
```

This is my Jquery/Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var productForm = $(".form-product-ajax") // #form-product-ajax
        productForm.submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // console.log("Form is not sending")
            var thisForm = $(this)
            //var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("action");
            var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("data-endpoint");
            var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
            var formData = thisForm.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: actionEndpoint,
                method: httpMethod,
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")
                    if (data.added) {
                        submitSpan.html("In cart <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Remove?</button>")} 
                    var currentPath = window.location.href
                    if (currentPath.indexOf("") != -1) {
                        refreshCart()
                    }
                },
                error: function(errorData) {
                    console.log("error")
                    console.log(errorData)
                }
            })
        })

        function refreshCart() {
            console.log("in current cart")
            var cartTable = $(".cart-table")
            var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
            // $(cartBody).empty()
            var productRows = cartBody.find(".cart-product")
            var cartTotal = cartTable.find(".cart-total-sec")
            var currentUrl = window.location.href
            var refreshCartUrl = '/api/cart/'
            var refreshCartMethod = "GET";
            var data = {};
            $.ajax({
                url: refreshCartUrl,
                method: refreshCartMethod,
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("success")
                    console.log(data)

                    if (data.products.length > 1) {
                        $(cartBody).empty()
                        productRows.html("")
                        $.each(data.products, function(index, value) {
                            console.log(value)
                            console.log(data.count)

                            cartBody.append("<tr><td>" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.price + "</td></tr>")
                        })
                        cartTotal.find(".cart-total").text(data.total)

                        console.log(data.total)



                    } else {
                        window.location.href = currentUrl
                    }

                },
                error: function(errorData) {
                    console.log("error")
                    console.log(errorData)
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct your `$.ajax()` call that you are expecting data in JSON format, so the `data` is parsed properly in your `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: refreshCartUrl,
    method: refreshCartMethod,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',  // <- here
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function(errorData) {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't think thats correct as the JSON parsing was working correctly for the other variables such as name and price. I have managed to resolve it and I just needed to add the correct syntax to retrieve quantity.

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question by adding what you did to solve the problem, it may help future visitors facing similar problem :-)